# Install Atlassian Confluence Server to Docker

Tags: installation, docker, timeout, confluence

I try to install Confluence Server in Docker. I tried as official image and also unofficial one. Problem is the same - failure on database step.

Steps to reproduce:

- install container
- make port 8005 accessible outside the server nginx (I guess could be replaced to any other reverse-proxy server)
- Visit main page http://..../
- Choose Trial install
- Check Confluence QA and Calendar
- Enter Confluence trial license key
- Choose DB options: Direct JDBC, database credentials
- Press "Next"
- Pages starts to load, but process takes toooo long. Then HTTP timeout gets exhausted, so I see 504 error page.
- When I check database I can see tables created by confluence - so DB was well available to Confluence installer.
- Next I wait until CPU usage of Confluence container goes down.
- I try to reload the installation page in browser and get error (see below pls)

How can I install Confluence to Docker?
Thank you!

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to register MBean [com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.TaskQueueWrapper@1dc0b1c9] with key 'Confluence:name=MailTaskQueue'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Confluence:name=MailTaskQueue

type Exception report

message Unable to register MBean [com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.TaskQueueWrapper@1dc0b1c9] with key 'Confluence:name=MailTaskQueue'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Confluence:name=MailTaskQueue

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
com.atlassian.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to register MBean [com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.TaskQueueWrapper@1dc0b1c9] with key 'Confluence:name=MailTaskQueue'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Confluence:name=MailTaskQueue
    com.atlassian.confluence.setup.actions.AbstractSetupAction.transitionFromColdToVacantState(AbstractSetupAction.java:161)
    com.atlassian.confluence.setup.actions.SetupStandardDatabaseAction.setupDatabase(SetupStandardDatabaseAction.java:46)
    com.atlassian.confluence.setup.actions.AbstractDatabaseCreationAction.execute(AbstractDatabaseCreationAction.java:36)
        ..... skipped .....
    The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.41 logs.
```

Comment: What is wrong with the official image? I just built a minimal `docker-compose.yml` file for it and MySQL and it worked fine after completing install.

Comment: Did you walk through all the steps? Could you show your Dockerfile and config files?

Comment: I made a gist of the `docker-compose.yml` and the steps I did: https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/2811642aed3721c078efd2a1598fa8c6

Comment: @AndyShinn I'm not sure how you can make that work, as the MySQL JDBC driver is not currently included in the standard Confluence docker image. Since PostGres and Sql Server drivers _are_ included, I'm guessing this is related to the same Oracle policy that prevents Atlassian using Oracle Java in their image.

Comment: You are right. My example is incomplete. I did have this working but I must have copied the library to my container and didn't catch those steps. The solution here is to probably rebuild the upstream image with the JDBC driver of choice.